# how to install duende identity server's mvc version in .net

Tags: .net, duende-identity-server

I want to use Duende's identityServer in my MVC project, but after following the steps in installing it the codes installed are in Razor pages but i want it to be in MVC, is there a way to solve this?

```
dotnet new --install Duende.IdentityServer.Templates

dotnet new isui
```

Comment: All `Duende.IdentityServer.Templates` samples use razor pages. If you want to use MVC you can start with the empty template (isempty) and then copy/paste from Identity4 templates in github. The most of the code will work as duende originates from it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the identity version 5.0.0

dotnet new --install Duende.IdentityServer.Templates::5.0.0

Comment: Proper formatting required